# Control de errores en c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, aplicación-escritorio

estoy trabajando una app de escritorio (Windows Forms) en c# con Visual Studio 2019, y me encuentro trabajando por capas: Entidades, Datos, Lógica y Presentación. El problema es que uno de los requisitos es tener un control de errores, esté tiene que registrar todos los errores en un archivo con extensión .txt en una carpeta del proyecto, de igual manera se deberá enviar al correo del administrador. Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Como puedo realizar esto? He leído en varios lugares pero no entiendo exactamente el cómo implementarlo. Gracias de antemano

Comment: en la capa lógica, en los try catch, crea un método asíncrono que lance un email. la configuración de correos electrónicos en C#, los puedes encontrar en todo el sitio, siempre hay preguntas iguales que terminan siendo cerradas por duplicadas. Mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=envio+de+correos+C%23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma mas simple de lograrlo sin tener que controlar todos con try..catch por todas las capas es hacerlo de forma centralizada para todas las exception cuando llega al punto mas alto de la ejecucion que seria la interfaz del usuario

Para esto debes hacer uso del evento

[Application.ThreadException Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

En el Main() que esta en Program.cs debes ubicar la linea de codigo

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

    Application.Run(new Form1());
}

static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    //aqui logueas en el archivo el e.Exception.Message
}
```

de esta forma cualquier error que de produzca sin importar en cual capa sea de la aplicaicon sera capturado con el evento